# Converting an array of int to an array of char and back via memcpy in c++

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I want to convert an array of int to an array of char and then back again,  for serialization purposes.
It does not need to work cross-platform.

I came up with

```
  //sample int array 
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,100};
  char char_arr[sizeof(arr)];
  //int arr to char arr
  memcpy(char_arr, arr, sizeof(arr));

  int newarr[sizeof(char_arr)/sizeof(int)];
  //char arr back to int arr
  memcpy(newarr, char_arr, sizeof(char_arr)/sizeof(int));
```

This does not seem to work however (newarr contains values different from arr). Any suggestions?

Comment: While you get the number of entries right in `newarr` the size when you copy to it is still `sizeof(char_arr)`, i.e. do not divide by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: You don't need to divide by `sizeof(int)` in the call to `memcpy`.

Comment: Think again whether you really need this. Perhaps a `reinterpret_cast<const char *>(arr)` will suffice for your application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third argument to `memcpy` is number of bytes<sup>*</sup>, not number of elements.  So your second `memcpy` call is incorrect.

---

<sub>* Number of `char`s, technically.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` copies memory bytes, not array elements and thus does no array element conversion for you. If you want to convert an array of chars to an array of ints you might try `std::copy` which copies containers element by element.

```
int newarr[sizeof(char_arr)/sizeof(char_arr[0])]; 
std::copy(&char_arr[0], &char_arr[sizeof char_arr/sizeof char_arr[0]], newarr);
```